# How can I reshape my data, moving rows to new columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, reshape2

I know that my problem is trival, however now I'm learing methods how to reshape data in different ways, so please be understanding.

I have data like this:

```
Input = (
 'col1 col2
  A 2
  B 4
  A 7
  B 3
  A 4
  B 2
  A 4
  B 6
  A 3
  B 3')
df = read.table(textConnection(Input), header = T)

> df
   col1 col2
1     A    2
2     B    4
3     A    7
4     B    3
5     A    4
6     B    2
7     A    4
8     B    6
9     A    3
10    B    3
```

And I'd like to have something like this, where the column names are not important:

```
      col1 v1   v2   v3   v4   v5
1     A    2    7    4    4    3
2     B    4    3    2    6    3
```

So far, I did something like:

```
res_1 <- aggregate(col2 ~., df, toString)
  col1          col2
1    A 2, 7, 4, 4, 3
2    B 4, 3, 2, 6, 3
```

And it actually works, however, I have one column and valiues are comma separated, instead of being in new columns, so I decided to fix it up:

```
res_2 <- do.call("rbind", strsplit(res_1$col2, ","))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "2"  " 7" " 4" " 4" " 3"
[2,] "4"  " 3" " 2" " 6" " 3"
```

Adn finally combine it and remove unnecessary columns:

```
final <- cbind(res_1,res_2)
final$col2 <- NULL
  col1 1  2  3  4  5
1    A 2  7  4  4  3
2    B 4  3  2  6  3
```

So I have my desired output, but I'm not satisfied about the method, I'm sure there's one easy and short command for this. As I said I'd like to learn new more elegant options using different packages.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do,

```
do.call(rbind, split(df$col2, df$col1))
#  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#A    2    7    4    4    3
#B    4    3    2    6    3
```

You can wrap it to `data.frame()` to convert from matrix to df

Answer (score 1):

The question is tagged with reshape2 and `reshape` so we show the use of that package and the base `reshape` function.  Also the use of dplyr/tidyr is illustrated.  Finally we show a data.table solution and a second base R solution using `xtabs`.

**reshape2** Add a group column and then convert from long to wide form:

```
library(reshape2)

df2 <- transform(df, group = paste0("v", ave(1:nrow(df), col1, FUN = seq_along)))
dcast(df2, col1 ~ group, value.var = "col2")
```

giving:

```
  col1 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1    A  2  7  4  4  3
2    B  4  3  2  6  3
```

**2) reshape** Using `df2` from (1) we have the following base R solution using the `reshape` function:

```
wide <- reshape(df2, dir = "wide", idvar = "col1", timevar = "group")
names(wide) <- sub(".*\\.", "", names(wide))
wide
```

giving:

```
  col1 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1    A  2  7  4  4  3
2    B  4  3  2  6  3
```

**3) dplyr/tidyr**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  mutate(group = paste0("v", row_number())) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "group", values_from = "col2")
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  col1     v1    v2    v3    v4    v5
  <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 A         2     7     4     4     3
2 B         4     3     2     6     3
```

**4) data.table**

```
library(data.table)

as.data.table(df)[, as.list(col2), by = col1]
```

giving:

```
   col1 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1:    A  2  7  4  4  3
2:    B  4  3  2  6  3
```

**5) xtabs** Another base R solution uses df2 from (1) and `xtabs`.  This produces an object of class c("xtabs", "table")`.  Note that it labels the dimensions.

```
xtabs(col2 ~., df2)
```

giving:

```
    group
col1 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
   A  2  7  4  4  3
   B  4  3  2  6  3
```

Comment: Wow, nice, it'll help me a lot in the future.